# How to set default value to a customed google protobuf type?

Tags: protocol-buffers, default-value

I have a google protobuf structure:

```
message ResourceProto{
    optional int32 memory = 0;
    optional int32 core = 1;
}
```

And I have another structure:

```
message AnotherProto{
    optional ResourceProto resource = 0 [default to ResourceProto(100,1)];
    ....
}
```

I know how to set default value to normal type like `int`, `String`, `Bool`, but how to assign default value to customed structure, what is the syntax? Say, set the default value of `resource` in `AnotherProto` to `memory = 100` and `core = 1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protocol Buffers doesn't support default values for fields of non-primitive types. 
Not sure why exactly, but I would assume this is because it is rarely needed in practice and tricky to implement:

- Arbitrary default values are rather difficult to self-describe in a consistent and portable way. Essentially you need to have a notion of a dynamically-typed `any` type, which is not supported by Protobuf2. Instead, they represent defaults as [optional string default_value](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/source/browse/trunk/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto#162) with some implementation-dependent syntax for the values.
- When you allow this in the definition language, you need to introduce syntax for structured default values. This is slightly more complicated than supporting syntax for primitive values alone.
- Depending on a target language, it may not be quite clear how to handle such default values at runtime with regard to dynamic object allocation and ownership. The safest option would involve copying which may result in unexpected performance hit.

That said, fundamentally, it *can* be done. For instance, I've implemented support for arbitrary defaults in [piqi](http://piqi.org) and it works well in OCaml and Erlang.

Comment: The reason they aren't supported is mostly just because of implementation complexity -- the generated code would have to construct constant instances of these default values, which is complicated, and almost no one actually wants this feature, so we didn't do it. That said, [Cap'n Proto](https://capnproto.org) actually does support default values for aggregate types (structs and lists). (Disclosure: I am the author of Cap'n Proto and also of most of the open source Protobuf code from Google.)

Comment: @KentonVarda is this still true for protobuf3 and 4?

Comment: @Rika Probably, but I haven't worked on protobuf since version 2 so I dunno. Also there's a proto4 now???

Comment: @KentonVarda thanks, yes there is a release candidate for now [rc2](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases)